# JavaScript: canvas height is not the same as value that I set

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas element that is set to be 608 pixels tall, however the measurements of the `canvas` element in the browser shows that the canvas element has a different height of 640 pixels.

I do not know why the canvas element shows a different height of `640px` even though I am setting the height to `608`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to keep in mind is that the `canvas` element has two concepts of height (and width).

The canvas as an HTML element has a "styled height" which describes the sizing of the `canvas` element in your HTML document.

The canvas also has it's 2D drawable surface, which has it's own "width and height" describing the resolution of that canvases drawable area.

These heights (and widths) are independent of one another, meaning that the canvases element size and drawable resolution can differ:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

/* 
Set canvas drawable height to something different of elements styled height 
*/
canvas.height = 608;

/* 
The canvas element is styled to 640px. This is possible because the 
resoultion height is independant of the styled height 
*/
console.log("canvas block height", window.getComputedStyle(canvas).height);

/* 
The resolution of the canvas height is the resoultion's height of the canvas
own drawable surface 
*/
console.log("canvas resolution height", canvas.height);
```

```css
canvas {
  /* Specify element size in document to height of 640px */
  height:640px;
  outline:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas />
```

To ensure that the height of the canvas is 608px, consider specifying this via CSS:

```
canvas {
  height:608px;
}
```

Comment: @jujumumu glad I could help :)